# Capture function argument type from actual arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, decltype

Is it possible to capture the type of a formal argument, having only the function name and the actual arguments?

I would need something similar to decltype, but it should return the function type instead of the return type of the function.

I found a half solution with C++11. If the function is not overloaded, you can use decltype to get the signature, specifying only the function name and template arguments (if any), but not the actual arguments:

```
template<class F>
struct my_function_traits;

// function pointer
template<class R, class Arg>
struct my_function_traits<R(*)(Arg)> : public my_function_traits<R(Arg)>
{
  typedef Arg type;
};

template<class R, class Arg1>
struct my_function_traits<R(Arg1)>
{
  typedef Arg1 type;
};

namespace itk
{
template <typename PixelType, unsigned Dimension>
class Image;
}

template <typename TPixel, unsigned VDimension>               
void func2(itk::Image<TPixel, VDimension>* image) {}


int main()
{
  typedef my_function_traits< decltype(func2<int, 2>) > Traits;

  Traits::type var = 0;

  return 0;
}
```

This works well, but if I add this other function, decltype will not able to resolve the type:

```
template <typename TPixel, unsigned VDimension>               
void func2(const itk::Image<TPixel, VDimension>* image, int i) {}
```

What makes sense, because the function name is ambiguous and both versions have the same template arguments. But the compiler must be able to figure out the correct function from the static type of the actual arguments. The problem is that as soon as I specify them, decltype returns the type of the expression, i.e. the return type of the function.

```
  itk::Image<int, 3>* image;
  int a = 3;
  ...
  typedef my_function_traits< decltype(func2<int, 2>(image, 3)) > Traits;
```

My main goal is to check the constness of the first argument.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't know the constness of the first pointer, and you know successive argument type, you may use the following:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct is_first_arg_const_ptr
{
    template <typename Ret>
    static std::false_type
    is_const(Ret (&f)(T*, Ts...));

    template <typename Ret>
    static std::true_type
    is_const(Ret (&f)(const T*, Ts...));

    // And for methods
    template <typename Ret, typename C>
    static std::false_type
    is_const (Ret (C::*) (T*, Ts...)) /* const volatile & && */;

    template <typename Ret, typename C>
    static std::true_type
    is_const (Ret (C::*) (const T*, Ts...)) /* const volatile & && */;

    // .. complete for all combinations of cv_qualifier and ref
};
```

And now, the overload is correctly chosen without ambiguity.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/MqusKN).

For the macro, you may do something like:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
constexpr
auto make_is_first_arg_const_ptr(T&& t, Ts&&...)
-> is_first_arg_const_ptr<
    typename std::decay<decltype(*t)>::type,
    typename std::decay<Ts>::type...
>;

#define IS_FIRST_ARG_CONST_PTR(Name, ...) \
    (decltype(make_is_first_arg_const_ptr(__VA_ARGS__).is_const(Name))::value)
```

And then use it as

```
static_assert(!IS_FIRST_ARG_CONST_PTR(func2, image), "");
static_assert(IS_FIRST_ARG_CONST_PTR(func2, image, a), "");
static_assert(IS_FIRST_ARG_CONST_PTR(&MyClass::func2, image, a), "");
```

Note that the macro will not work for some prototype of `func` as I deduce type from argument but you will get a compile error in this case (you may change `std::decay` by a more appropriate traits to match your need).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the successive argument type. I know only the type of the first argument that is a pointer to a const or not const image.

Comment: So how do you want to select between `func2(const image<TPixel, VDimension>*, int)` and `func2(image<TPixel, VDimension>*)` ?

Comment: Based on the actual arguments. I have a function call expression, and want to get the specs of the function that is going to be called. This information is available at compile time.
Look at the last code block in the question. The operand of the decltype operator is an expression. The compiler resolves the function call based on the static type of the formal arguments, and the result of the decltype operator will be the return type of that function.

But I am not interested in the return type (it's gonna be void always). I want to know the which function it is.

Comment: @espakm: From your example, from where comes `int a = 3;` ? Can we assume that the second type is an `int` ? Or can it be a type convertible from `int` (as `long`, `unsigned int`, ...) ?

Comment: This is just a test code. I want to write a macro that takes a function name (let's call it 'access function'), an input image and other arguments (if the access function need any). Then it converts the image to ITK, applies a read/write lock on the input image depending on if the access function takes the converted image as const, and calls the access function.
Really, that's all what I know. The name of the access function, the template parameters, and the type of the first argument except the constness. The access functions can be overloaded.

Comment: I have just add a macro which may help you. it doesn't manage all cases but it may be enough for your needs.

Comment: That is it. :) It works per for global functions. I had to remove the Ret template argument because it did not compile here. I replaced it with void. Do you think it's possible to make it work for member functions as well?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I tried g++ 4.8.1 and clang 500-2.79 and it does not compile if the is_const declarations have template arguments. I could remove the 'Ret' by replacing it to void, but don't know what could I do with the class name.

Comment: works with gcc 4.9, clang 3.4 (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6146ee98293d008b) (clang produces warnings), and here I use g++ (tdm-2) 4.8.1

Comment: Thanks, I see the difference now. In my scenario, the first argument is 'templated', and the access functions are templated as well. Like in the example in the original post. Your code compiles here as well. But with template function it works only if I remove the template arguments of is_const. I can do it with Ret, because it's always 'void' in my case, but for the member functions I cannot remove the class parameter.

Comment: I amended the code with templated parameters.
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d2404ca0b762f22

The is_first_arg_const_ptr part works, but the make_is_first_arg_const_ptr and the macro does not.

Comment: @espakm: I got your error when uncommented code at the end. it is because MACRO dislikes comma in a parameters, so `MACRO(fun3<float, 2>, &d)` sees 3 parameters whereas you expect 2. The work-around is to use extra parenthesis, so use `MACRO((fun3<float, 2>), &d)` instead.

Comment: @espakm: for the class parameter, you may create an other helper class `template <typename C, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct is_first_arg_const_ptr_for_class` and then `is_const` won't be template and that should solve your issue.

Comment: comma issue: such a banal reason! Thank you so much for all your help, that was extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Boost does this. Have a look at boost's function_traits:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/type_traits/function_traits.hpp

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html

Comment: It seems that the OP's problem is to select the correct overload between the functions, not the *function_traits* part.

Comment: Exactly. I have not managed to solve this with boost. I tried the function traits and boost::bind as well.